# Are Dart 1.x books still relevant?

Tags: dart

Are the Dart 1.x books still relevant, now that Dart 2 is released? Dart 2 documentation only points to a migration guide. I am trying to learn Dart and was wondering if I should buy one of the Dart 1.x based books or should wait for the publication of Dart 2 based books

Comment: [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dart 1 books will be about 80% correct. The problem will be sussing out the 20%.

The type system is VERY different in ways that can be surprising.

I'd start with https://dart.dev/guides

The language is moving pretty quickly. No book you get will be as updated as you want!